# Possible to pipe command using su via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo, pipe, su

I'm trying to write a python script to remotely update the login passwords for a set of account I administer - I can already successfully use python to pipe remote commands via the stdin of an ssh process. However, I want to test whether the remote password is correctly set. I can do this I can do this remotely follows:

```
[localhost]% ssh -t -o RequestTTY=true  user@host
[host]% su user -c true
```

and provide the password at the prompt. This works, but if I try the following remotely:

```
 [localhost]% echo "su user -c true" |  ssh -t -o RequestTTY=true  user@host
```

I get:

```
su: must be run from a terminal
```

Note, this is not failing because su needed a password (which I'll eventually provide via python) - it fails before then. su doesn't like to be run through a pipe in this way.

What's going on, and how can I pipe input to a remote su command? (or remotely test whether a password is correct for some user).

Comment: one solution is to log remotely as a root, which will skip the `su` problem. Otherwise, you can try two `-t` switches, which should force TTY allocation even when there is no terminal on local side.

Comment: This seems to be a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the password into the `su`, which in turn is piped to `ssh`.

Example below.  Note how foopass is the correct password for user foo, so it runs the `id` command happily.  Note how badpass is the wrong password for user foo, so it generates Authentication failure.

```
$ echo "echo foopass | su foo -c id" | ssh -t -o RequestTTY=yes steve@localhost
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Password: uid=1001(foo) gid=1003(foo) groups=1003(foo) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
$ echo "echo badpass | su foo -c id" | ssh -t -o RequestTTY=yes steve@localhost
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Password: su: Authentication failure
$
```

Comment: echo "echo password | su -c true" | ssh user@localhost still gives 'su: must be run from a terminal'

Comment: `su -V` shows me to be on "su from util-linux 2.24.2" and works fine here.  Perhaps worth expanding your question to include your su version?

Comment: su: invalid option -- 'V'.  Is whatever is provided with Ubuntu 14.0.4